# respond to keypresses in python without generating a window

Tags: python, event-handling, wxpython, keypress, arrow-keys

I'm doing some robotics programming in python, and I'd like to enable the keyboard to control the robot's movement. My only experience with something like this is writing a game in Java using SWT, and I imagine the basic idea here would be to make some keyboard event handlers and run a main execution loop.

From what I've read it seems like the recommended way to do this would be to use some kind of GUI library like pyglet or wxPython(no experience with any of them). However, I understand these require some kind of main window or canvas to operate, and I just want the keypress handling capabilities.

So, what's the most straightforward way to program keypress responses?

Comment: And then give that window the focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use pykeylogger http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pykeylogger/index.php?title=Main_Page

However using something like PyGame or wxpython is easiest, so are you absolutely sure you can't use those? For example, why can't you have a window initialized? Is your robot controlled by some sort of embedded microchip that can't handle windows? In that case, how is a keyboard connected?

You should probably describe exactly how your robot is constructed.

Comment: PyGame is fine, I was just wondering if there was something simpler.. it seems like unnecessary hassle to worry about a canvas when all I want is to detect keypresses

Comment: The thing is that at a low-level the interface between keyboard and computer is actually more complicated than you'd expect. If you really must use a keyboard then we'll need more low-level details, such as your OS. Most GUI libraries have the keyboard interface abstracted away, but for simple buttons to control a robot I would actually go to Radio Shack and buy a few basic buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Pyro? http://pyrorobotics.org/

If you're using something like Lego Mindstorms, there's http://code.google.com/p/nxt-python/